# Loading yolo model not working?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm building a CNN yolo model, when I'm loading the model

```
json_file = open('model.json', 'r')

loaded_model_json = json_file.read()

loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
```

I'm getting a strange error:

```
NameError: name 'tf' is not defined
```

then I realized it's coming out from a method

```
def space_to_depth_x2(x):
    return tf.space_to_depth(x, block_size=2)
```

Which I built, and using in The cnn model through:

```
skip_connection = BatchNormalization(name='norm_21')(skip_connection)
skip_connection = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)(skip_connection)
skip_connection = Lambda(space_to_depth_x2)(skip_connection)
```

so I think the problem with the `Lambda` and I should try some other method?

Comment: do you have tensorflow installed and `import tensorflow as tf` in your file?

Comment: Please don't abuse bold formatting

Comment: of Course, I have installed `tensorflow` as `tf` :D

Answer (score 2):

You have to define `tf` inside Lambda layer!

try this:

```
def space_to_depth_x2(x):
    import tensorflow as tf
    return tf.space_to_depth(x, block_size=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `import tensorflow as tf` in your python script.